# mIRC socket is not working

Tags: mirc

This socket is not working, I tried everything but it never actually displays the quote. Just the text beforehand.

```
on $*:TEXT:/^[!@](motivate|mqod|mqotd)/Si:#:{ if ($chan !isin %notlist) {
    if ($sock(Motivation)) { notice $nick Please try again in a few seconds. | halt }
    set %Motivation $iif($left($1,1) == @, msg $chan, notice $nick) $col
    sockopen Motivation motivateus.com 80
} }
on *:SOCKOPEN:Motivation: {
  sockwrite -nt $sockname GET /thoughts-of-the-day.htm HTTP/1.1
  sockwrite -nt $sockname Host: motivateus.com 
  sockwrite -nt $sockname $crlf
}
on *:SOCKREAD:Motivation: {
  if ($sockerr) { halt }
  else {
    var %sockreader | sockread %sockreader 
    if ($regex(%sockreader,(.+)&quot;<br>)) {
      %Motivation $+ Today's motivational quote is: $regm1(1) $+ 
      unset %Motivation | sockclose $sockname
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a lot of experience with mIRC but isn't it supposd to be $regml, not $regm1?

Answer (score 2):

I have a script on my computer that changes the font of numbers so I can see that kind of error :)